# loop through string to find substring

Tags: c#, string

I have this string:

```
text = "book//title//page/section/para";
```

I want to go through it to find all // and / and their index.

I tried doing this with:

```
if (text.Contains("//"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(" // index:  {0}  ", text.IndexOf("//"));   
}
if (text.Contains("/"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("/ index:  {0}  :", text.IndexOf("/"));    
}
```

I was also thinking about using:

```
Foreach(char c in text)
```

but it will not work since `//` is not a single char.

How can I achieve what I want?

I tried this one also but did not display result

```
string input = "book//title//page/section/para"; 
string pattern = @"\/\//";


Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
 if (matches.Count > 0)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", input, matches.Count);
      foreach (Match match in matches)
         Console.WriteLine("   " + input.IndexOf(match.Value));
 }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the expected output for `///`? `{0}`? `{0, 1}`? Something else?

Comment: I cleaned up the code formatting, grammar, and punctuation a bit in hopes of making it easier to understand.

Comment: I have tried this but does not work string input = "book//title//page/section/para"; 
            string pattern = @"\/\//";
            
                
                Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", input, matches.Count);
                    foreach (Match match in matches)
                        Console.WriteLine("   " + input.IndexOf(match.Value));
                }

Answer (score 9):

Simple:

```
var text = "book//title//page/section/para";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, "//?"))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found {0} at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index));
```

Output:

```
Found // at index 4.
Found // at index 11.
Found / at index 17.
Found / at index 25.
```

Answer (score 4):

Would it be possible using Split?

So:

```
string[] words = text.Split(@'/');
```

And then go through the words? You would have blanks, due to the //, but that might be possible?

Comment: You can use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries so you don't get blanks, too.

Comment: In this case, you might *want* the blanks.  Every blank (that's not the first or last in the array) will be between a pair of slashes.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is a list "book","title","page","section","para"
you can use split.

```
    string text = "book//title//page/section/para";
    string[] delimiters = { "//", "/" };

    string[] result = text.Split(delimiters,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
    Assert.IsTrue(result[0].isEqual("book"));
    Assert.IsTrue(result[1].isEqual("title"));
    Assert.IsTrue(result[2].isEqual("page"));
    Assert.IsTrue(result[3].isEqual("section"));
    Assert.IsTrue(result[4].isEqual("para"));
```

Comment: Actually what I need is not book,title,..so on .. I need / and // and its positions

Answer (score 1):

Sometin like:

```
bool lastCharASlash = false;
foreach(char c in text)
{
    if(c == @'/')
    {
      if(lastCharASlash)
      { 

          // my code...
      }
      lastCharASlash = true;
    }
    else lastCharASlash = false;
}
```

You can also do `text.Split(@"//")`

Comment: Timwi's regex is probably the better way to do this.

Answer (score -2):

You could replace // and / with your own words and then find the last index of

```
string s = "book//title//page/section/para";

        s = s.Replace("//", "DOUBLE");
        s = s.Replace("/", "SINGLE");

        IList<int> doubleIndex = new List<int>();

        while (s.Contains("DOUBLE"))
        {
            int index = s.IndexOf("DOUBLE");
            s = s.Remove(index, 6);
            s = s.Insert(index, "//");
            doubleIndex.Add(index);
        }

        IList<int> singleIndex = new List<int>();

        while (s.Contains("SINGLE"))
        {
            int index = s.IndexOf("SINGLE");
            s = s.Remove(index, 6);
            s = s.Insert(index, "/");
            singleIndex.Add(index);
        }
```

Remember to first replace double, otherwise you'll get SINGLESINGLE for // instead of DOUBLE. Hope this helps.

Comment: This would go pretty badly if the text were, say, `"/SINGLE//SINGLE/DOUBLE/"`.

Comment: Agreed. Didn't think of that. I guess you could use regex

Comment: no it is good point since this will be bookdDOUBLEtitleDouble...etc but still the problem has not been solved which this will not loop to check all time of Double and Single appear in the text

Comment: Sorry didn't realise you wanted all indexes. I've update the code above to reflect your solution. It could be done in a cleaner way, but it gives you an idea.